# Discord.py load json data

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a bot for multiple servers with costum settings and I'm using this:

**Guild_Settings.py**

```py
import json

class LoadGuildSettings:

    def get_prefix(self, message):
        try:
            with open('config/server_prefix.json', "r") as fp:
                prefixes = json.load(fp)
            return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
        except IOError:
            return
    def get_command_channel(self, message):
        try:
            with open('config/server_command.json', "r") as fp:
                prefixes = json.load(fp)
            return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
        except IOError:
            return
```

**main.py**

```
async def on_message(message):
    name = message.author
    c = guild_setings.LoadGuildSettings().get_command_channel(message)
    cmd = guild_setings.LoadGuildSettings().get_prefix(message)
    if not message.channel == c:
        return
```

Now my problem is :

```
if not message.channel == c:
```

is not working but

```
if message.content.startswith(cmd+'tc')
```

It's working fine.

Comment: I believe your issue is that you're attempting to get the `name` or `id` of a channel `message.channel` is an object.  If you're trying to get the `id`, try using `message.channel.id` or `message.channel.name`

Comment: What do you mean by: `is not working` ?

Comment: c is the ID from a channel but when I setup the ID in my json and will post in there then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what `get_command_channel()` returns, as you haven't shown your json file, but I'm gonna assume it's a (list of) `string` or `int`. Your code that "is not working" is trying to compare a `discord.Channel` instance to `strings`/`ints`, which will always return false, so it will always get inside the `if`-statement and `return`. I suggest you store & compare thet `id's` of the channels instead.

EDIT: After more info provided in the comments

Yes, you're indeed trying to compare a `discord.Channel` instance to a `string`. You simply have to get the `id` out of the channel first.

```
if not str(message.channel.id) == c
```

Comment: `{
    "529728546281881600": "756110597162008626",
    "740287395416506369": "749196789445427200"
}`
First is Guild ID secound is channelID

Comment: Thanks I will try later and give feedback